# Is the network load balancer of a web farm affected by GC strain?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, clr, load-balancing

Can the resources of one machine in a web farm be affected to such a point by an app running with Garbage Collection Mode = "server mode" such that the network load balancer will adjust for it?

Comment: I think you can use the before-gc event to tell the load balancer that this instance doesn't want to receive any more requests and the after-gc event to tell it that you want requests again. I don't know if that's a good idea since I never worked on such a big site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network load balancer is not "sensitive" to GC, in a sense it doesn't know when or where it happens. It may attempt to do some funky stuff with checking the "load" on the machine, but usually it hurts performance and a simple round robin turns out to be better a approach for most of the scenarios.

At the enterprise level one usually totally disregards GC, it is too much complexity on the macro level.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Garbage Collection notifications. This will allow you to implement such a system with a minimum effort.

Reference here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713687(v=vs.110)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713687%28v=vs.110%29)

If you are using high end NLB's you may want to watch in the specs for supporting .NET GC Notifications, you might be surprised.